# evento antes de destruir la sesion

Tags: php, sesiones

buenas tardes mi pregunta es si puedo ejecutar una función php antes de que se destruya la sesión por ejemplo en mi caso la sesión se destruye cuando se cierra el navegador porque asi es requerido, entonces lo que quisiera poder hacer es ejecutar una función como actualizar el estado  de activo a inactivo en la base de dato

Answer (score 0):

Sí, puedes destruir una sesión en cualquier momento, no es necesario que esperes a que se cierre el navegador. Para ello utilizas esta función de PHP

[Ver manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-destroy.php)

```
session_destroy();
```

Después de destruir la sesión, puedes hacer perfectamente un query a la base de datos.

Espero haberte ayudado